# Display Alert to specific user

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsalert

I have a C or C++ executable which is running as root. From this executable I need to ask logged in user for some input. So I packaged this GUI code in a dynamic library, which can be linked with my C or C++ executable to get user input. But the problem is with fast user switching option in Mac OS X. If there are two users had logged in at the same time how do I show this alert to a specific user? Is CFUserNotificationCreate useful in this scenario ?

Comment: Can any body please help.

Comment: you have to have 2 processes for this. as Apple also recommends that background processes/daemons should not have UI. for UI a user process is recommended instead of root.